# Is there a way to catch the exception of an STL function not being given right arguments?

Tags: c++, exception, stl, c++17

I am using std::stol() to convert string to long type. However, if the user enters letters how do I ensure the exception gets caught?

The code can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62607424/is-there-a-way-to-have-exceptions-work-indefinitely).

Note: I have already got the right way for that question, I just need to know what to do instead of:

```
if ( !(stol(input)) ) // Yes, I know it's stupid to think the output would be bool
    throw 'R';
```

Answer (score 2):

`std::stol()` throws exceptions on input errors. Use a `try..catch` to catch them.

Answer (score 1):

From a comment to another answer, there seems to be some ambiguity about the goal here. To answer the question in the title, to catch an exception you write a `try ... catch` block:

```
long get_value() {
    for (;;) {
        std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
        std::string text;
        std::cin >> text;
        try {
            return stol(text);
        } catch(...) {
            std::cout << "Invalid input\n";
        }
   }
}
```

But the comment suggests that the solution of scanning the entire input text to see if there's a letter anywhere is appropriate. If the goal is to require that the input consist only of digits, you don't need to scan every character before calling `std::stol`. It's smarter than you think.

```
int last;
std::stol(text, &last);
if (last != text.length())
    // got a bad character
```

This detects input like `"123q"`.

As always, **read the documentation**.